# Using Piecewise to create a periodic waveform

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, piecewise

I want to create a piecewise function that repeats after `t=T`.

```
Clear[t, T, s];
T = 5;
s[t_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {t, 0 < t <= 1},
   {1, 1 < t <= 2},
   {-t + 3, 2 < t <= 3},
   {0, 3 < t <= T}
  }
```

To make it periodic, I add the following:

```
s[t_] := s[t - T] /; t > T
Plot[{s[t], Evaluate@D[s[t], t]}, {t, 0, 12}, Exclusions -> None]
```

It plots alright, but the derivative of `s[t]` stops at the end of `T`.

[image]

**Question** What is the correct way of defining and plotting the derivative and integral of a periodic waveform defined using the `Piecewise` function?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: `Plot[{s[t], D[s[x], x] /. x -> Mod[t, T]}, {t, 0, 12}]`?

Comment: That's three good solutions on one page using `Mod`. kglr's solution (in the comments) is to find the derivative for the base case and plot it using `Mod` for different ranges. Nasser's solution is suitable for teaching canonical use of `Piecewise`. It defines a base function and then defines a periodic function based on it, perhaps using `T` as a parameter. Ted Ersek's solution shows the [Gibb's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) that alludes to MMa's use of `Series` being used in the background. My thanks to all the respondents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be

```
Clear[t, T, s, s0];
T = 5;
s[t_] := Piecewise[{{s0[Mod[t, T]], t > T}, {s0[t], True}}]
s0[t_] := Piecewise[{{t, 0 < t <= 1}, {1, 1 < t <= 2}, {-t + 3, 
    2 < t <= 3}, {0, 3 < t <= T}}]
```

and now

```
Plot[s[t], {t, 0, 12}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[s[t], t]], {t, 0, 12}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
Plot[{s[t], Evaluate[D[s[t], t]]}, {t, 0, 12}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate why my method fails for the derivative but not for the plot?

Comment: @Syed  I just noticed that when you had `Clear[t,T,s];
T=5;
s[t_]:=Piecewise[{{t,0<t<=1},{1,1<t<=2},{-t+3,2<t<=3},{0,3<t<=T}}]; s[t_] := s[t - T] /; t > T` then `D[s[t],t]` gives zero for `t>3`. But changing it to  `s[t_]:=Piecewise[{{s0[Mod[t,T]],t>T},{s0[t],True}}];
s0[t_]:=Piecewise[{{t,0<t<=1},{1,1<t<=2},{-t+3,2<t<=3},{0,3<t<=T}}]` now `D[s[t], t]` now  gives correct derivatives mod T.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[s];

s[t_?(0<=#<=5&)]:=\[Piecewise]{
  {t,0<=t<=1},
  {1,1<t<=2},
  {-t+3,2<t<=3},
  {0,3<t<=5}
};

s[t_?(Element[#,Reals]&)]:=s[Mod[t,5]];
```

---

Edit by @Syed (to include plot)

```
Plot[{s[t], Evaluate[D[s[t], t]]}, {t, 0, 12}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

**** Edit ****
The derivative plotted above has errors.

Wolfram Tech Support said:
Since there are conditions on the input, there is no symbolic derivative, so s'[real number] is computing an approximate derivative, which is of very low quality.

Another solution is given above that works much better.