# How to express a periodic piecewise linear function in terms of Mod function? or linear combination of Mod?

Tags: functions, function-construction, discontinuity

I am programming a small game (**with other programming language**) in which I have to use `Mod` function to express **piecewise linear** period functions.

In my case, two hard parts I think exist.

(1) The periodic function is linear in the **piecewise** sence, like the function below. In a full period it is **NOT linear**.

(2) There are **NO** powerful function like `Piecewise` function in Mathematica, and all I can use are some very basic functions including `Mod`, `+`,`-`, `*`, `\`, `Abs`, `Floor`, `Ceiling`,`Exp`,`10^`,`Sin`,`Cos`,`Tan`,`ASin`,`ACos`, `ATan`,`Log` and logic control commands `If`, `If Then Else`.

(3) After many times trying, I also found another challenging part is related to  **`Mod` of a negative number** .My piecewise linear periodic function can thake **negative integers** whose `Mod` is so confusing to me. I can calculate the `Mod` of a negative number by hand, but I have no clear idea how it relates to a repeat pattern.

So is it possible to use Mathematica to find something like linear combinations of `Mod` functions for any periodic piecewise linear function?

For example, the periodic piecewise linear period function like this:

```
f[x_?IntegerQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{-10 x + 2, 1 <= x < 4}, {-5 x + 8, 4 <= x <= 10}}, True]
f[x_?IntegerQ] := f[x + 10] /; x < 1
f[x_?IntegerQ] := f[x - 10] /; x > 10
ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -9, 20}]]
```

Any advices are highly appreciated! Thanks :)

[image: some period piecewise linear function]

Comment: What about `period = 10; ListPlot[Table[{x, Mod[x, period, 0]}, {x, -9, 20}]]`?

Comment: Partly similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261450/using-piecewise-to-create-a-periodic-waveform).

Comment: Thanks, but in my problem the repeated part is a combination of two different linear functions, that is the linear functions on [1,4) and [4,10] are different.

Comment: @Syed, yes, partly similar. Maybe some linear combination of `Mod` can do this?

Comment: Does your other programming language's `mod()` function work exactly like `Mod[]`? I doubt it: Both `Mod[x, m]` and `Mod[x, m, x0]`? `Mod[x + m, m] == Mod[x, m]`, even when `-m < x < 0`? It seems necessary to know how the functions in both Mathematica and the target language work to know how to solve the problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for you answer, very inspring. Actually, my target programming language is Scratch (https://scratch.mit.edu/), and it dosen't support `Mod[x, m, x0]` and `Mod[x + m, m] == Mod[x, m]`. My naive idea is to use a guess form of `Mod` linear combination to fit the data generated by original piecewise linear function. I will think more on your great answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to take advantage of Mathematica's code generation capabilities. In particular we take advantage of two internal workhorses, `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` and `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression ``.  You should check to see if your library has a unit step function, and if so, you can just use the output of `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``, inserting `x = Mod[y, 10]` for input `y`, and avoid the rest of the trickery.

```
(* Auxiliary functions *)
ifArithmeticRules = {
   Times[z_, If[c_, a_, b_]] :> With[{i = If @@ {c, a*z, b*z}}, i /; True], 
   Plus[z_,  If[c_, a_, b_]] :> With[{i = If @@ {c, a+z, b+z}}, i /; True]};
compileToTempVars = 
  With[{c = #[[1, 1]]}, # /. 
     Thread[c -> Block[{nnn = 1}, Symbol["tmp" <> ToString[nnn++]] & /@ c]]
   ] &;

Simplify`PWToUnitStep[
      Piecewise[{{-10 x + 2, 1 <= x < 4}, {-5 x + 8, 4 <= x <= 10}}]
      ] // ReplaceAll[{
       x -> Mod[x, 10],             (* adjust if Mod[] != mod() *)
       UnitStep -> (Inactive[If][#>=0,1,0]&)  (* is translating UnitStep[] necessary? *)
       }] // 
    Experimental`OptimizeExpression //
   Activate //     (* If had to be Inactive[] for condition to be optimized *)
  compileToTempVars //              (* optional: change variable names *)
 ReplaceRepeated@ifArithmeticRules  (* not needed if you can use UnitStep[] *)
```

> ```
> (*
>   Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4},
>     tmp1 = Mod[x, 10];
>     tmp2 = -4 + tmp1;
>     tmp3 = tmp2 >= 0;
>     tmp4 = If[tmp3, 1, 0];
>     If[10 - tmp1 >= 0,
>      If[-1 + tmp1 >= 0,
>       -2 (-1 + 5 tmp1) (1 - tmp4) + (8 - 5 tmp1) tmp4,
>       (8 - 5 tmp1) tmp4],
>      If[-1 + tmp1 >= 0, -2 (-1 + 5 tmp1) (1 - tmp4),
>       0
>       ]]]]
> *)
> ```

Comment: You'll have to adjust `Mod[x, 10]` if your `mod()` function works differently.